# Alternative to LinkBuilder for creating urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app where I'd like to build a url from a lambda e.g.

`string url = MagicUrlBuilder<HomeController>(c => c.Foo("Name"))`

At first I read about the `LinkBuilder` class, but it looks like that does not exist in the official ASP.NET MVC releases.

Is there another class available that can do the same thing?

Comment: FWIW, the class exists in the MVC4Futures NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I could take a look at the code for that class, see if I can create my own version for my MVC 5 stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're on MVC5, you should look at the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures package.

Comment: Ah cool, I wasn't aware about that. Thanks again.